# How to sum numbers with text appended in the same cell [Excel]?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I've tried summing numbers for the entire column by using the sum() function but I get 0 as an answer due to a string present.

Example :

- 1.99 USD
- 22.37 USD
- 2.49 USD
- 1.69 USD

Is there a function that only calculates/sum the number?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4," USD",""))
```

Comment: I think it should be `=SUMPRODUCT(-SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4," USD",""))`. Above expression will generate negative value

Comment: @Shailesh  Please note that I used a ***double negative sign*** , not single.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the USD from the values in the cell and use a custom number format of,

```
0.00 \U\S\D
```

Then sum the raw numerical values.

[image]

Comment: Thx. I've discovered the similar method a few hours ago which is the "Search and Replace" function. Silly me. Easy solution instead of trying the hard way

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution (if you just want to sum them up, without further computations) would be to use the "Search and Replace" function CTRL+H. Silly me for not realizing this earlier.

In my case, it's " USD" with a blank space in front (ignore the open-inverted commas) and inserting nothing at all in the "replace with" parameter.